# How to change background color for canvas in Storybook.js?

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook

The default seems to be a black background, but I would like to have a white one. I tried to use the light theme, a custom theme and the background add on, but no matter what I do I can not change the color of the canvas.

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be that the HTML body is set to black in the main css of the application.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering how to change the background color just for one `<Canvas />`, in Storybook, just apply the style prop:

```
<Canvas style={{background: "red"}} >
```

I personally expected some prop added by Storybook for this stuff, but I was unable to find one so I tried this, which worked.

Answer (score -1):

I added a custom-preview.html and added a style info for the body tag there.

Comment: Elaboration on what you did specifically would be beneficial.